# Elasticsearch query not giving result, and shows pending request

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I've created a node.js API, which fetches result from Elasticsearch based on the request parameters. When i hit the API, it shows the request as pending when there is data in the elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch Query:

```
{
  "partial_fields": {
    "basic": {
      "include": [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "a" : "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

When I check the status in Debug console, it shows status as **PENDING**. I don't know where i'm going wrong. Could somebody explain how should i approach to solve this problem ?

**EDIT**:

Elasticsearch version is : 2.1.1

Node.JS error:

> Unhandled rejection [search_parse_exception] failed to parse search source. unknown search element [partial_fields]

Comment: Could you please specify the eleasticsearch version and Node.JS error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite evident from the error that elasticsearch is not able to identify/parse the term *partial_fields*. I looked up the ES site, and they have mentioned that ES doesn't support partial_fields term since version 2.x. Instead they recommend using source filtering. Please use the follow [post](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_search_changes.html#_partial_fields?q=partial%20fields) for the changes in 2.x regarding source filtering.

Please change your query to use source filter as follows:

```
{
  "_source: [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "a" : "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```

**OR**

You could downgrade your ES version to < 2.x and then run the query.